# How to make OAuth authentication and use Instagram API properly these days?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I'm added as a developer into a FB and Instagram bussiness account. A bussiness has been fully verified, all the documents and settings have been set up. However, there haven't appeared **Instagram** app ID and secret anywhere. There're, however, an app_id and secret of Facebook in the dashboard.

I've tried to use them to authenticate via Instagram. It didn't work.

I open this url in the browser:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<my_app_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/instagram-oauth&response_type=codescope=user_profile,user_media
```

Then I enter my login/pass and then I get this error on an html page:

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Invalid platform app"
}
```

What's the matter? If I have to use **Instagram app_id and secret**, but where are they in the dashboard? There're only those of Facebook there, not of Instagram.

My goal is to authentificate at Instagram, in order to then be able to make API calls to Instagram from **the server side**.

Comment: That API is basically deprecated. It mostly goes through Facebook Apps now. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

Comment: @ceejayoz I've seen that documentation dozens of times. The question is what the steps will have to be precisely

Comment: @ceejayoz the endpoint is still in use, but for authentication within the Instagram Basic Display API (that's the one for "normal" IG user accounts; anything to do with business / creator accounts, indeed needs to use the Instagram Graph API.)

Comment: @CBroe my question is about the concreate steps I'll have to take. What will they be?

Comment: Those are outlined under "Getting Started" - but you need to pick the right API to begin with. If you want to do things with an IG business account, then you need to follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

Comment: @CBroe I've done everything outlined there. Hence, my question why it hasn't worked

Comment: Because you are using the _wrong_ API to begin with ...? You IG account is a _business_ account, is it not? Then you need to implement the standard Facebook login first of all, either the JS version, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web, or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow

Comment: @CBroe but in the docs you've pointed me to is mentioned the wrong API. Shouldn't I follow the docs as you've suggested me?

Comment: The endpoint `api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize` you tried to use, is not mentioned _anywhere_ on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started - so what are you talking about?

Comment: @CBroe  it's mentioned somewhere still -- at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-authorize/

Comment: Instagram Graph API, and Instagram Basic Display API, are two very different things. Again: If you want to work with an IG Business or Creator account - then you need to use the former, whereas you are still looking at the documentation for the latter.

Comment: @CBroe where is that explained in the documentation?

Comment: Right on the entry page ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram

Comment: @CBroe now you're right.